# C# Teststack.White automating Winforms Menu (ControlType.Menu) which is not child of the main window

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, white-framework

I am automating a legacy WinForms application using **Teststack.White**, and I've encountered a problem.
The menu which shows-up after right-clicking some item, for some reason **appears to be outside the main application window** in UI Hierarchy:

[image: VisualUIVerify UI hierarchy]

What is the best way to approach automating this menu?
Our test framework is build around a window hierarchy, and we access items which are children of the main application window.

Right now we approach this problem by using *Keyboard arrows* to select menu items and clicking *Enter* (which is not the best solution, I suppose).

Is there a better way to solve this in Teststack.White? Thank you!

Comment: Native popup menu is inside the app process, but it's a top-level window like the main form. I'd recommend to search it with process_id condition to not bother another processes for performance reasons. I'm not familiar with White, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the right click menu if you search under all desktop windows. See code below:

//Call the function GetCurrentPopUpMenu

```
        PopUpMenu pop = GetCurrentPopUpMenu();

        pop.Item("Add Child").Click();
```

//The GetCurrentPopUpMenu function

```
    PopUpMenu GetCurrentPopUpMenu()
    {
        List<Window> windows = WindowFactory.Desktop.DesktopWindows();
        foreach (Window w in windows)
        {
            if (w.Name == "") return w.Popup;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution.
I was expecting some approach, without going over top-level windows, however as I think about it now, it is probably the only possible solution.